# rvest scraping get empty table

Tags: r, web-scraping

I try to use many ways to scrape the following table from website https://f3.vietstock.vn/APC/tai-chinh.htm?tab=KQKD

[image]

I investigate xpath of the table is //*[@id="finance-content"]/div/div/div[4]/div/table. Therefore, I use the below code

```
require(rvest)
require(XML)                                                  
require(RCurl)

doc<-read_html('https://f3.vietstock.vn/APC/tai-chinh.htm?tab=KQKD')

Data_table <- doc %>%
  html_nodes(xpath ='//*[@id="finance-content"]/div/div/div[4]/div/table') %>%
  html_table()
```

However I got empty for `Data_table`.

Comment: examine `cat(as.character(doc))` and you'll see the page as downloaded is not like the page as displayed (the table is generated by a script run when you open the site)

Comment: Thank you @MichaelChirico Could you help me by give some suggestions of code to get Data_table as I mentioned. Please!

Comment: Despite the question showing absolutely no research effort, the code in the answer should be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Use Developer Tools in your browser and you'll see that the site uses *many* XHR requests (this is a topic *extensively* covered on SO, which means the research effort was minimal for this question).

[image]

The highlighted one has the data that makes the table.

If you switch over to "Headers" from "Response" you'll see XHR is done via `POST` request:

[image]

that means a simple `jsonlite::fromJSON()` isn't going to work with the URL.

I used the [`curlconverter`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) package to automagically make a request function for this. Right click on the highlighted line on the left and choose "Copy as cURL" then follow the directions in the README and manual pages in `curlconverter` (there are also *many* SO answers using `curlconverter` in a similar context, so — again — virtually no research effort).

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://f3.vietstock.vn/data/financeinfo",
  body = list(
    Code = "APC", 
    ReportType = "KQKD",
    ReportTermType = "2", 
    Unit = "1000000",
    Page = "1", 
    PageSize = "4"
  ),
  encode = "form"
) -> res

dat <- httr::content(res)

str(dat[[2]][[1]][[1]])
## List of 25
##  $ ID                   : int 1
##  $ ReportNormID         : int 2206
##  $ Name                 : chr "1. Doanh thu bán hàng và cung cấp dịch vụ "
##  $ NameEn               : chr "1. Revenue"
##  $ NameMobile           : chr "1. Doanh thu bán hàng và cung cấp dịch vụ "
##  $ NameMobileEn         : chr "1. Revenue"
##  $ CssStyle             : chr "NormalB"
##  $ Padding              : chr "Padding1"
##  $ ParentReportNormID   : int 2216
##  $ ReportComponentName  : chr "Kết quả kinh doanh"
##  $ ReportComponentNameEn: chr "Income Statement"
##  $ Unit                 : NULL
##  $ UnitEn               : NULL
##  $ OrderType            : NULL
##  $ OrderingComponent    : NULL
##  $ RowNumber            : NULL
##  $ ReportComponentTypeID: NULL
##  $ ChildTotal           : int 0
##  $ Levels               : int 0
##  $ Value1               : num 46365
##  $ Value2               : num 45103
##  $ Value3               : num 34182
##  $ Value4               : num 45497
##  $ Vl                   : NULL
##  $ IsShowData           : logi TRUE
```

You can find the rest of the nested list elements on your own.